# Where are the cursed tombs?

Tags: torchlight-2

I am searching for Boris the Stout and several sources say he randomly appears in the cursed tombs.  Where is this place?  I am surprised that there is very little info on Google about this place.

Comment: Borris the Stout appears in many random locations.  I don't think anyone knows which place has the highest chance of him appearing, so just keep looking around.  Crow's pass is an easy place to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "Cursed Tombs" are one of the maps you can buy from the map seller in the Mapworks (once you've beaten the game). Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Cursed Tombs Map]

That said, you can definitely find Borris the Stout randomly in other locations. Here's another screenshot showing him in one of the act 1 levels (the level in case you can't make it out is *Watchweald Temple - Floor 2*):

[image: Borris the Stout]

Comment: Confirmed on the Cursed Tombs scroll.  However, still can't locate that POS enchanter.  Really ticks me off.

Comment: They can indeed be hard to find, sometimes. That said, since I posted this answer, I've seen the guy three times! Makes no sense...